# How to select a <select> element on the basis of selected option text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Suppose there are many `<select>` elements in a form. I need a selector that selects a `<select>` element whose selected option has certain text. To explain, let's say there are 5 `<select>` elements of class "color". Each of them have 3 `<option>` with texts "white", "black", "green". Now I need to select the elements whose selected option is "white".

```
<select class="color" > 
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1"> white </option>
  <option value="2"> black </option>
  <option value="2"> green </option>
</select>
```

In the scenario as depicted in the below image, I need to select those two white `<select>`s.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying for this http://jsfiddle.net/HFTLD/1/ i was not sure so i posted it as comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$("select.color option:selected:contains(white)").parent();
```

This will get you all the select elements having text that starts with **white**

**Note:** It will also match **whitesmoke**

EDIT: the following code will give you the exact value.

```
var requiredelements = $("select.color option:selected").filter(
    function()
    {
    return ( $.trim($(this).text())=== 'white')
    }).parent('select');

alert(requiredelements.length);
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sudhAnsu63/QGq84/)

Comment: For exact matching of 'white', you could use jquerys .filter() with a selfmade function in it to match the text ( `...===white`)

Comment: @ManojShrestha The first One will fail if you have similar color with same start name like white and whitesmoke.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$('select.color option:contains(white)').prop('selected','selected');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cHHM5/)

Select all the elements whose selected option is "white".

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/cHHM5/2/)

```
$('select.color option:contains(white):selected').parent('select');
```

Match Exact value

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/cHHM5/3/)

```
$('select.color option:contains(white):selected').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == 'white'){
        $(this).parent('select').css('color','blue');
    }
});
```

Comment: this will select the item, the OP wants it that if you select a colour its highlighted

Comment: or maybe i am the one who is mistaken :)

Comment: This will get the same even if white is not selected

Comment: The user wants to select the select elemnets, that has exactly the text white, not the options or not the options that starts with white.

Comment: @TusharGupta you are getting the select elemnet if it has a option that starts with white, it may or may not be selected.

Comment: $('select.color option:contains(white)').prop('selected','selected');

It sets all the <select> elements with "white" text.

Comment: Now you have added :selected, but still it will fail when you have both **white** and **whitesmoke**

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select.color').each(function(index, element) {
 if($(this).find('option:selected').text()=='white') {
  // do something with select box which contains white text or use array to get all contents
 }
});
```